# Rep features list on Stack Apps

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, faq-update-request, stackapps

This is totally pedantic because I realize rep doesn't matter on Stack Apps (and no one is going to read the FAQ page), but can we sort the rep features by rep anyway?

[alt text http://img444.imageshack.us/img444/20/repfeatures.jpg](http://img444.imageshack.us/img444/20/repfeatures.jpg)

Comment: Note that it's the same on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: I wonder why *Create New Tags* off is? Why not just 100?

Comment: Same on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

The site is very new, I guess commenting, tagging, and ads are just really to encourage the growth. And those could be temporary, so IMO, no problem with current ordering.

Comment: I don't see why the actual rep thresholds and their corresponding rationale should affect the sort order.  It does look kind of silly, even on meta.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, please.

It also means that I can see what the *next* power I could get will be.  "Ooo... if I get only another X upvotes, I can then do Y, and that'd be nice.  I wonder if there's a question I can answer..."

Answer (score 0):

To the more orderly among us, it does look odd that its not in ascending or descending order. However, I suspect (Jeff or someone can back me up/correct me) its in the order people are most likely to be looking at the list of "How much rep do I need to ____" fill in the blank.

Voting, flagging, and commenting (though I would think the #2 and #3 should be switched) are probably the most common "Huh?" moments for new people, and if they are the sort to read (via their own direction or by way of someone linking to the FAQ) they will find their answer faster.

We could probably quibble over the rest and/or look at the data for related questions to fine-tune the order, but in light of the above, it looks to be roughly correct.

Tangentially related: http://www.useit.com/alertbox/alpha-sorting.html

---

Seems I'm a little late to this question... saw it on the front page and never bothered to look at the date. For whatever its worth, I'll leave the answer as another way of looking at it.