# SO FAQ rep limits are out of order

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, faq-update-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rep features list on Stackapps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51002/rep-features-list-on-stackapps)

I know they were [changed recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51949/should-the-create-new-tag-threshold-be-increased).  Here's an excerpt from the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)

```
250     Vote to close, reopen, or migrate your questions
1500    Create new tags
500     Retag questions
```